# Powertop shows ~30W, and fans working somewhat hard, during light internet browsing

Tags: 18.04, power-management, 18.10

I have an **MSI GS65**, on which I installed 18.04 alongside Windows 10.

Things are generally going well, but I notice my fans are often going at a moderate clip, and the battery life is not so great. Running **powertop** at the terminal shows I'm often drawing **nearly 30W**! System monitor reveals CPU's are not under particular strain (mostly closer to 0% than 20% usage) and RAM is ~33% usage.

I'm having a little bit of difficulty further diagnosing the problem. I don't think it's the nvidia drivers (I'm using nouveau drivers), but I could be wrong. I've also already **installed tlp**, and set all powertop tunables to 'good'.

I'll be very grateful for any ideas.

EDIT: Still having this problem on 18.10

Comment: If possible turn off the nVidia and use Intel iGPU instead: `sudo prime-select intel` (using nVidia drivers but I'm not sure about Nouveau drivers) -- heat could drop by 20 degrees C and battery life much longer.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely your Nvidia drivers. Nvidia drivers aren't the best on Linux and will draw **really** much power. On Windows you have Optimus technology which automatically swap between Nvidia and Intel cards, but on Linux you would need to do this yourself from the Nvidia x server, which is a program that gets installed when you apply the Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: You know, I remember looking into this before, and trying to open nvidia x server. It won't open!

Comment: Go into the software and updates, the icon looks like a package, then on additional drivers, click on Nvidia proprietary drivers, it's above the xorg drivers. Apply, restart and you should be good to go.

Comment: The Nvidia proprietary drivers were already checked off. But I have two options for nvidia drivers: 396 and 390. 396 was checked off -- should I try 390?

Comment: Yes, you need to turn them on :)

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify: they were already checked on. So I couldn't click on them and then apply changes.

Comment: Can you try this, and then open the settings program?: sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79633/discussion-between-russell-richie-and-mth1417).

Answer (score 1):

It's nvidia. Switching prime to intel doesn't work. Ubuntu still keeps the GPU running 100%. I don't know why they haven't fixed it yet.

Comment: Think maybe it's fixed in the 18.10 release today?

Comment: Seems like it is. Although I'd prefer to stay on LTS.

Comment: did you see this solution that @Yumi posted? I think this might have done the trick for me...: https://github.com/matthieugras/Prime-Ubuntu-18.04

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience, for me it was caused by an update to ubuntu-drivers-common. Downgrading to ubuntu-drivers-common version 1:0.5.2 fixed the issue.

To check if this helps, I'd recommend using synaptic.

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

In Synaptic, find the package ubuntu-drivers-common and highlight it. Select "Package" then "Force Version" and select version 1:0.5.2 (bionic). Apply changes and reboot. Check Powertop and see if it's gone down.

If this helped, you'll want to prevent ubuntu-drivers-common from updating. To do so, run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-mark hold ubuntu-drivers-common
```

This can be undone using:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold ubuntu-drivers-common
```

If this didn't fix your problem, you can use synaptic to update ubuntu-drivers-common back to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm still a bit of a linux noob. How do I do that?

Comment: @RussellRichie I edited the post to include some instructions. Let me know if you have any questions. Hope it helps you too.

Comment: I installed Synaptic, found ubuntu-drivers-common, clicked on "Package", but 'Force Version' is greyed out? I googled a little bit and someone suggested just using sudo apt-get at the command line. Is that right?

Comment: @RussellRichie deselect "Automatically Installed" in synaptic and then force version should be available. But yes, you should be able to use apt-get as well. Try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-drivers-common=1:0.5.2`?

Comment: thanks for the additional help, but 'automatically installed' was already deselected. I tried selecting and deselecting it, but that didn't work. I also tried using apt-get like that, and it said `E: Version '1:0.5.2' for 'ubuntu-drivers-common' was not found`. I should add that, since I made this post last July, I upgrade to 18.10. Maybe I should edit the OP accordingly.

Comment: @RussellRichie oh I see! On 18.10 you'll need to add the Bionic repository before you can downgrade to the Bionic version of ubuntu-drivers-common. Do `sudo add-apt-repository  'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main'
` then try the above steps again.

Comment: okay, I was now able to take the steps you recommended. Thanks so much! Now to see if this helps my battery life and fan....I'll report back in a few days!

Comment: Let me know, I have the same laptop running 18.10 and my power usage is down to ~12 watts average with the intel gpu.

Comment: Still having problems. I think the issue is actually, as others have suggested here and elsewhere, that my laptop keeps using the nvidia gpu even when `sudo prime-select query` tells me it's intel. I also learned that the orange light between the keyboard and display means the nvidia gpu is being used. How on earth did you get the gs65 to use the intel gpu on 18.10....?

Comment: @RussellRichie You could try applying this patch: https://github.com/matthieugras/Prime-Ubuntu-18.04 It's for 18.04, but I use it on 18.10 still and haven't had any problems switching between intel/nvidia since.

Comment: Wow, that might have worked! I passed the 'check' on their how-to, and the indicator light is now white. Chrome doesn't seem to work so well now (window flashes and is unresponsive), but I could get used to Firefox. Powertop indicates around 10W, and estimated battery life is around 8 hours! Now to see if the fan quiets down too! Thanks!!!

Comment: @RussellRichie to fix the buggy chrome when using Intel run `sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel` and reboot. Let me know if that doesn't fix it.

Comment: that worked! Thank you so, so much for all your help!